# Not able to authenticate Askbot with LDP authentication provider

Tags: python, django, ldap, askbot

Not able to authenticate Askbot django application on Ubantu 18.04

Able to ping the LDAP server, but still it says - "Can't contact LDAP server"

Error logs shows:-

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/srv/askbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/askbot/deps/django_authopenid/ldap_auth.py",
>   line 127, in ldap_authenticate_default
>       get_attrs   File "/srv/askbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py",
>   line 854, in search_s
>       return self.search_ext_s(base,scope,filterstr,attrlist,attrsonly,None,None,timeout=self.timeout)
>   File
>   "/srv/askbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py",
>   line 847, in search_ext_s
>       msgid = self.search_ext(base,scope,filterstr,attrlist,attrsonly,serverctrls,clientctrls,timeout,sizelimit)
>   File
>   "/srv/askbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py",
>   line 843, in search_ext
>       timeout,sizelimit,   File "/srv/askbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py",
>   line 331, in _ldap_call
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)   File "/srv/askbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py",
>   line 315, in _ldap_call
>       result = func(*args,**kwargs) SERVER_DOWN: {u'info': 'Transport endpoint is not connected', 'errno': 107, 'desc': u"Can't contact LDAP
>   server"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping uses the ICMP protocol. LDAP uses a TCP connection to (usually) port 389 (or 636 for LDAPS). Those are two different things.

So the fact that you can ping the server only means the server is online. It doesn't mean that the LDAP service is running or that a firewall is not blocking TCP traffic to the right port.

You can test opening a TCP connection to the right port on Ubuntu in one of two ways:

```
telnet yourserver 389
```

Or,

```
nmap yourserver 389
```

More information on that [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/188429/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-open-for-remote-systemubuntu).

You may have to install telnet or nmap for those to work. And if you're using LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) then you should test port 636.